# AWS S3 Lifecycle Rules Not Transitioning into Glacier, not sure what the issue is?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, lifecycle

I have this CFT that creates a S3 bucket with lifecycle rule to transition into Glacier immediately but it's not working they are still in standard after a couple of days.  Any help would be appreciated thanks.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Description: Template to setup lifecycle configuration

Parameters:

  BucketName:

    Type: String

    Description: Name of the bucket on which lifecycle configuration will apply

    Default: lifecycle-config-testing-bucket

Resources:

  DemoBucket:

    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'

    Properties:

      BucketName: !Ref BucketName

      LifecycleConfiguration:

        Rules:

          - Id: Transition all objects in the bucket after immediately 

            # Prefix: "" 

            Status: Enabled

            Transitions:

              - TransitionInDays: 0

                StorageClass: GLACIER

            ExpirationInDays: 365

Outputs:

  BucketName:

    Value: !Ref DemoBucket

    Description: Name of the sample Amazon S3 bucket with a lifecycle configuration.
```

Comment: Welcome. Can you please post it all as one CloudFormation file instead of breaking it up? Would be easier :)

Comment: I just checked my objects and they have transitioned to Glacier.  It takes a bit longer than expected which was throwing me off, and thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1):

S3 lifecycle transitions have minimum age rules which needs to be true for each object. You can't immediately move a file directly to glacier after uploading it in S3.

Generic lifecycle policy could be
S3 (standard) -> 30days -> S3 (Infrequent Access) -> 60days -> Glacier

Check the details on the minimum number of days from the documentation.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-transition-general-considerations.html

Comment: Yes, I read that section too, however, if you read it careful S3 to Glacier is possible.  If you are transitioning to Glacier IA then it must stand there for a minimum of 30 days.  My objects in my S3 bucket has now transitioned into Glacier, I may have assumed that it should transition within a day but in reality it's more like 1-2.5 days.